# golang sync.WaitGroup doesn't complete on Linux

Tags: go

I have ping function which works fine on Windows, but not on Linux. On Linux it pings few hosts and stops (doesn't exit).

```
    func main() {
    ...
wg.Add(len(hosts))
    for _, ip := range hosts {
            go ping(ip, &wg, os)        
        }
        wg.Wait()
    ...
    }
```

I can ping hundreds of hosts on Windows but not on Linux. Look at https://github.com/irom77/go-public/blob/master/gping/main.go for the whole thing

```
    func ping(ip string, wg *sync.WaitGroup, os string ) {  
        _ , err := exec.Command("ping", os, *PINGCOUNT, "-w", *PINGTIMEOUT, ip).Output()    
        if err == nil {
            count++
            fmt.Printf("%d %s \n", count, ip)
        } 
wg.Done()
    }
```

When printing result (adding 'result' inside func ping)

```
result , err := exec.Command("ping", os, *PINGCOUNT, "-w", *PINGTIMEOUT, ip).Output()
fmt.Printf("%s\n", result)
```

I just got correct output , but it doesnt continue to ping next IPs

```
....
--- 10.192.167.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 476.564/476.564/476.564/0.000 ms

49 10.192.167.1
```

expecting more IPs here (fine in Windows)

Comment: Where are you adding and removing things from the WaitGroup?

Comment: If you're adding to the waitGroup in the goroutine itself, this is probably what will happen.

Comment: I am adding 'wg.Add(len(hosts))' just before for loop in main(). Never remove anything, there is 'wg.Wait()' just after for loop

Comment: so if you are not doing `wg.Done()` anywhere, why will this ever end?

Comment: oh..there is wg.Done() as last instruction in the func ping, I will update it asap. Not sure how it get removed ..added link to github

Comment: If some of the commands aren't returning, you need to debug why. Maybe connect them directly to stdout/stderr and see if there's any clues in the output. If they are returning, get a stack trace and see where you're blocking.

Comment: in general it looks okay, but there might be a file descriptor limit issue or something like that.

Comment: You're not printing errors, maybe they just fail?

Comment: Please post what errors you're getting after adding error handling

Comment: I'm with @JimB on this: I'd modify the `ping` function to prepare an `os/exec.Cmd` instance which `stderr` and `stdout` are connected to those of the process, and see whether some of the executables being run actually fail.

Comment: would be better if you copy the error

Comment: I updated question with result, never did debug before, will learn asap;)

Comment: I think I found the problem...Windows ping is in 'ms', But Linux in 's'. So default 1000ms is in fact 1000s in Linux and program start to wait after it encounter first non-pingable IP ;(

Comment: ping on Linux does not return, it continues - in contrast to Windows which return only 4 lines by default.

Answer (score 1):

You may be ignoring panics here, change your ping function to:

```
func ping(ip string, wg *sync.WaitGroup, os string ) {
    defer wg.Done()
    defer func(){
       if err := recover(); err != nil {
           fmt.Println("Error with:",ip,"err:",err)
       }
    }()
    result , err := exec.Command("ping", os, *PINGCOUNT, "-w", PINGTIMEOUT, ip).Output()
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", result)
    if err == nil {
        count++
        fmt.Printf("%d %s \n", count, ip)
    } else {
        //fmt.Printf("%s is dead\n", ip)
    }
}
```

this should print the panic, if it happens, as well as guarantee to call wg.Done()

// note: didnt run this, but it's directionally correct

Comment: While a panic would skip the non-defered `wg.Done`, the original wasn't recovering so a panic would be evident, and nothing in that function should panic anyway.

Comment: yep, you are right, for some reason i thinking it was dropped silently